# Speech Recognition using service

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have an Android application that uses speech recognition in an Activity.  I would like to port this over to a service so I can talk to the application while it's running in the background.

However, as far as I know, the speech recognition service has to use onActivityResult, which is unavailable for Services. Is there a way to either contain an Activity in a Service such that its GUI is not displayed, or perform speech recognition in a service instead of an activity?